# How to create trigger to block certain program name except if the login is within a specific AD group?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to be able to stop Microsoft Office applications from connecting to my SQL database except if the login used is part of a specific AD group.

Only those within said AD group should be able to connect to the database with any Office application. This is even possible?

SQL Server 2012 Enterprise.

I know they're configured for the whole server, but I'm thinking of creating a trigger. I've created a table that is constantly updated with the AD users and created the below join. What I need is for everyone that is returned by this query to access the database with their desired Office app, and everyone who isn't returned to be rejected.

```
SELECT A.LOGIN_NAME, A.PROGRAM_NAME, B.LOGIN NAME
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions A
JOIN AD_Group_Members B ON A.login_name = B.LOGIN NAME
WHERE session_id = @@SPID
  AND program_name IN (N'2007 Microsoft Office system', N'Microsoft Office', N'Microsoft Office 2016', N'Microsoft Office 2013', N'Microsoft® Mashup Runtime')
```

I can't test this because I cannot get my hands of an adequate testing environment :/

So, would this work? Is there a better way of conducting this?

I know how to write the trigger, I'm just looking at getting the meaty bit right as I don't fancy blocking the wrong connections on a production box.